# SSH into Windows 10 using key pairs

Tags: windows-10, ssh

I'm trying to SSH into my Windows 10 machine from my Raspberry Pi.
I've already been able to do this quite easily but the problem I'm facing at the moment is getting Windows to accept my private key.

In the windows console I've created a key pair and appended my public key to `C:\Users\user\.ssh\authorized_keys` but when I try and connect from the Pi, it's still asking me for my password.

So now that I'm thinking that it isn't even reading that file, it's reading from somewhere else, or I need to allow public key authentication in the config. But I don't know where any of that is in Windows 10.

So my question is, is this actual possible with that I want to do? Or am I stuck with entering in the password when I want to SSH into Windows?

Comment: any logs would be helpful.

Comment: What logs? @jakuje

Comment: Any log from client and server. Client has `-vvv` switches, server has `LogLevel DEBUG3` options, but I have no idea where does it go under Windows.

Comment: That's the issue I'm having, I can't find where anything is stored on Windows, otherwise I'd have no problem editing the sshd_config file or whatever it's called

Comment: What SSH server are you running?  There are half a dozen all with their own quirks on Windows.  Microsoft's early alpha.  Something  you compiled in WSL, a cygwin version of SSH, something commercial?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I think it might be cygwin as that is where the ssh keys I generate get saved automatically

Answer (score -1):

## Set Up `key-auth` Package

[This HowTo on Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) says you have to set up the `key-auth` package before Windows 10 will accept key-based authentication.

> If you need key-based authentication, run the following to setup the key-auth package:
>
> ```
>    `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file install-sshlsa.ps1`
> ```
>
> (for Win7 and Server 2008, see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/189))
>
> ```
>    `Restart-Computer`
> ```